# Record API path and payload with logs when Error log is generated in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am looking out for solution which can help me to record API Endpoint with Request Payload for debugging purpose on Laravel.

Right now I am able to find Error log generated by Laravel framework when some error is occurred. But I want to log API request payload data when request is failed.

Original Laravel Log when Error is generated:

```
[2022-09-15 17:40:17] developer.ERROR: Division by zero {"userId":205,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Division by zero at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bm_api/apis/app/Http/Controllers/API/ReportController.php:916)
[stacktrace]
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bm_api/apis/app/Http/Controllers/API/ReportController.php(916): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Division by zer...', '/Applications/M...', 916, Array)
#1 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Controllers\\API\\ReportController->list_xxx_size_wise_purity_report(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bm_api/apis/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
.....
```

I want to add some other details to this framework generated logs as below

```
[2022-09-15 17:40:17] developer.ERROR: Division by zero {"userId":205,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Division by zero at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bm_api/apis/app/Http/Controllers/API/ReportController.php:916)
[request_details]
API: [API_PATH]
DATA : JSON
PAYLOAD: {.......}


[stacktrace]
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bm_api/apis/app/Http/Controllers/API/ReportController.php(916): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Division by zer...', '/Applications/M...', 916, Array)
#1 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Controllers\\API\\ReportController->list_xxx_size_wise_purity_report(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bm_api/apis/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey Laravel have class to manage error handling you can find it in
`App\Exceptions\Handler` so you can add you data in register function, after each error throw out laravel call this class automatically